# how to get my config values in yml - using dropwizard guice D.I?

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard

I am using below `config.yml`

```
# AWS DynamoDB settings
dynamoDB:
  # Access key
  aws_access_key_id: "access-key"
  #Secret Key
  aws_secret_access_key: "secret-key"
  aws_dynamodb_region: EU_WEST_1
```

And below class to read the above config values in my `DynamoDBConfig` class.

```
public class DynamoDBConfig {
    public DynamoDBConfig() {
    }

    @JsonProperty("aws_access_key_id")
    public String accessKey;

    @JsonProperty("aws_secret_access_key")
    public String secretKey;

    @JsonProperty("aws_dynamodb_region")
    public String region;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Finally `ApplicationConfig` class which include `DynamoDB` config.

```
public class ReadApiConfiguration extends Configuration {
    @NotNull
    private DynamoDBConfig dynamoDBConfig = new DynamoDBConfig();

    @JsonProperty("dynamoDB")
    public DynamoDBConfig getDynamoDBConfig() {
        return dynamoDBConfig;
    }

    @JsonProperty("dynamoDB")
    public void setDynamoDBConfig(DynamoDBConfig dynamoDBConfig) {
        this.dynamoDBConfig = dynamoDBConfig;
    }
}
```

Now i want to read `aws_access_key` and `aws_secret_key` values in my `AWSclient.java` class to create a `awsclient`

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_key_id");
```

My problem is, how i read/inject the **config values**, in my `AWSClient` class. I am using the `dropwizard-guice` module for DI. and couldn't figure out , how can i bind the `configuration` object created at the DW startup time to its class.

P.S. :-> I've gone through this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882330/how-to-get-my-configuration-values-in-yml-using-dropwizard-microservice-jers) but it doesn't solve my issue, as its not using guice as a DI module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can inject your configuration object either into a class field or into a constructor, like:

```
public class AWSclient {

  @Inject
  public AWSclient(ReadApiConfiguration conf) {
     initConnection(conf.getDynamoDBConfig().getSecretKey(), ...)
  }

}
```

Additionally, annotate your ReadApiConfiguration class with the  @Singleton annotation.

Comment: But still i need to create the AWSClient from my application class only where `run(final ReadApiConfiguration configuration,
                    final Environment environment) ` method has config param. how can i create from other part of the application ?

Comment: You don't have to create it there. Inject your AWSClient wherever you need it. Guice should take care about creating its instance and providing a configuration object into the constructor.

Comment: i need to bind AWSClient somewhere in guice-bundle correct ? i still don't understand how guice will create its instance. Could you share piece of code if any related to guice or is it done oftb?