# @Context injection not working in Jersey ContainerRequestFilter (Dropwizard)

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

@Context injection works with classes but not able to make it work with Objects.

httpServletRequest in ContainerRequestFilter produces null pointer.

Dropwizard Version:- 1.1.0

ContainerRequestFilter

```
public class ApplicationIPAuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationIPAuthFilter.class);
    private HerculesRestAccessor restAccessor;
    private String applicationName;

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    public ApplicationIPAuthFilter(){
    }

    public ApplicationIPAuthFilter(HerculesRestAccessor accessor, String applicationName) {
        restAccessor = accessor;
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // need remote Ip
        String remoteIp = this.httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
        ....
    }
}
```

DynamicFeature

```
@Provider
public class ApplicationIPAuthFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    private final HerculesRestAccessor accessor;
    private final String applicationName;

    public ApplicationIPAuthFeature(HerculesRestAccessor accessor, String applicationName) {

        this.accessor = accessor;
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        if (resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(ApplicationIPAuthRequired.class) != null) {

            // not working
            context.register(new ApplicationIPAuthFilter(accessor, applicationName));

             //@Context injection works in ContainerRequestFilter for classes
            //context.register(ApplicationIPAuthFilter.class);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch remote ip in ContainerRequestFilter to authenticate request based on ip.

How do I fix this.. need help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's a known issue with DynamicFeature](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3438). Injections don't work when registering as an object.

One thing you can do is manually inject it, like mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953104/2587435).

Another thing you can do is make the `HerculesRestAccessor` and the `applicationName` injectable. Or rather then making the application name injectable, you can make it a configuration property and [inject the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35883457/2587435). If you do this, then you can register the filter as a class, and all the injections should work.

Comment: @peeskillet..Thanks..:) Will go with injecting both the fields and register the filter as a class.